# Starting to learn AngularJS, where I can have ebook

Tags: angularjs

I'm Vietnamese, my new projects start using AngularJS that is new for me. I only used jQuery before. I would know the steps to learn AngularJS and ebook for beginner like me.

Thanks
Trung

Comment: you should use google for this. well check out eggHead videos and subscribe to ng-newsletter read the website of angularjs

Answer (score 1):

Angular has a rich community, and when it comes to learning something that is community driven then IMHO, what better place than their own tutorials:

http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/index

Comment: I remember having an awfully hard time trying to find good Angular resources... this was a couple of years ago, now, though.